# Where can pressure gradient force be classified?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, forces, pressure, interactions

I know that there are four fundamental forces of nature, and they govern everything that happens in the universe. And all the forces which we experience is one among them. But I could not figure out where pressure gradient force be classified among these four fundamental forces?

Comment: you should look out for the cause of pressure gradients first .

Comment: Do you understand the nature of forced produced by uniform pressure?

Comment: no... this question came in my head when i was studying diffusion and effusion ... The molecules of gases are pushed towards lower pressure region due to a huge pressure difference. But I could not understand the nature of this force .

Answer (score 2):

Pressure is just abstraction over forces - any forces. If you have some surface submerged in a fluid, the molecules of a fluid will interact with the surface and exert some net force on it. Pressure is then simply the perpendicular component of this force divided by area of the surface. The pressure gradient means, that if the surface has finite thickness, the force exerted on it from one side does not have the same strength as the force exerted from other side. This only means, the fluid is in different internal state in various places.

The nature of the forces is not specified, as we are interested in net force and not particular interactions. That being said, the forces are usually of electromagnetic nature.